# Show Jtable scrollbar only when Jpanel size is full

Tags: java, swing, jtable, jpanel, jscrollpane

```
    There are three panels inside a JFrame.

     1. Parent panel (Using GridBaglayout)
        i. Table panel 1 containing JTable (Using normal Border layout) & JScrollPane
        ii.Button panel 2 containing "Add Row" and "Delete Row" button. (Using flow layout)

    Requirements:

     1. Add row and delete row buttons should add and delete table rows respectively.
     2. The panel 1 size should increase/decrease with addition and deletion of rows. For this I have used: table.setPreferredScrollableViewportSize(table.getPreferredSize());

     3. Scroll bars should appear only when panel 1 + panel 2 fills up the parent panel
```

I cannot keep on doing table.setPreferredScrollableViewportSize(table.getPreferredSize()), everytime a new row is added else, the scroll bar will never appear as per below rule:

```
Vertical scroll bar appear only when the component size (in this context, table) becomes larger than the view port size.
```

Need help to find the condition on when to stop doing table.setPreferredScrollableViewportSize(table.getPreferredSize()), or is there a different way to for the requirements above.

```
    package practice;

    import java.awt.BorderLayout;
    import java.awt.Color;
    import java.awt.FlowLayout;
    import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
    import java.awt.GridBagLayout;

    import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
    import javax.swing.JButton;
    import javax.swing.JFrame;
    import javax.swing.JPanel;
    import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
    import javax.swing.JTable;
    import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
    import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;

    public class TableExample3 {

        private DefaultTableModel tableModel;

        public void createAndShowGui() {
            JFrame frame = new JFrame("Table size test");
            frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

            JPanel panel = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());

            JPanel tablepanel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
            JTable table = new JTable(4, 4);
            table.setFillsViewportHeight(false);
            tableModel = (DefaultTableModel) table.getModel();
            JScrollPane pane = new JScrollPane(table);
            tablepanel.add(pane);

            GridBagConstraints gc = new GridBagConstraints();
            gc.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
            gc.gridx = 0;
            gc.gridy = 0;
            gc.weightx = 1;
            panel.add(tablepanel, gc);

            JPanel buttonPanel = new JPanel(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.LEFT));
            buttonPanel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEtchedBorder());
            JButton addButton = new JButton("Add");
            JButton deleteButton = new JButton("Delete");
            buttonPanel.add(addButton);
            buttonPanel.add(deleteButton);

            table.setPreferredScrollableViewportSize(table.getPreferredSize());

            Object[] data = null;
            addButton.addActionListener((evt) -> {

                tableModel.addRow(data);

                // if (has to be some condition here when tablepanel + buttonPanel
                // fills up the panel) {

                table.setPreferredScrollableViewportSize(table.getPreferredSize());

                panel.revalidate();
                panel.repaint();
            });

            deleteButton.addActionListener((evt) -> {
                int rowCount = tableModel.getRowCount();
                tableModel.removeRow(rowCount - 1);
                pane.getViewport().setPreferredSize(table.getPreferredSize());
                panel.revalidate();
                panel.repaint();

            });

            gc.gridy = 1;
            gc.weighty = 1;
            gc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.NORTH;

            panel.add(buttonPanel, gc);

            frame.getContentPane().add(panel);
            frame.setVisible(true);
            frame.pack();
            frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
            frame.setExtendedState(JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);

        }

        public static void main(String... args) {
            TableExample3 example = new TableExample3();
            SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> example.createAndShowGui());
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want your viewport to get a reasonable height (independent of the initial number of rows)
you may change your initialization from

```
table.setPreferredScrollableViewportSize(table.getPreferredSize());
```

to something like

```
Dimension preferredTableSize = table.getPreferredSize();
preferredTableSize.height = 100;
table.setPreferredScrollableViewportSize(preferredTableSize);
```

But most importantly, in the action handlers for "Add" and "Delete" don't do anything like
`setPreferredSize`, `setPreferredViewportSize`, `revalidate`, `repaint`,
because it does more harm than good.

```
addButton.addActionListener((evt) -> {
    tableModel.addRow(data);
    // nothing more needed here
});

deleteButton.addActionListener((evt) -> {
    int rowCount = tableModel.getRowCount();
    tableModel.removeRow(rowCount - 1);
    // nothing more needed here
});
```

Then the scrollbar will appear and disappear as needed.

Comment: The add/delete button should be just after the last row of the table. If I do,

Comment: The add/delete button should be just after the last row of the table. If I set table view port size as you said, those buttons will appear quite far after the last row. Also, as soon as new row is added, the table panel should grow in size to accommodate that row until the entire panel fills up (i.e by increasing the size of tablepanel and decreasing the size of lower grid cell containing button panel). Now when the next row is added, since there is no space, a scroll bar should appear.

Comment: @user2596386 Then it is probably better to ignore the first half of my answer